# Electron JS cookies/session not persisting between windows

Tags: session, cookies, electron

I'm opening a web page in Electron, if a user opens a second instance of the app, it does not carry the session over.

I have tried using app.requestSingleInstanceLock() to open a new window every time a user opens the app again instead of having multiple main instances open at once but the issue still persists.

Am I missing something really dumb here?

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, session, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const Store = require('electron-store')
const store = new Store()

const cookiePartition = 'persist:urlsession'

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1929,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      partition: cookiePartition
    },
  })

  let isSingleInstance = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()
  if (!isSingleInstance) {
    app.quit()
  }
  
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  win.loadURL('https://url.com')
  win.maximize()
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  if (store.get('admin-mode') === undefined) {
    store.set('admin-mode', true)
  }
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)
  createWindow()
})

app.on('second-instance', () => {
  createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (!store.get('admin-mode')) {
    const ses = session.fromPartition(cookiePartition)
    ses.defaultSession.clearStorageData([], (data) => { })
  }
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```